# How to adjust the right side margin of UIToolbar so that it can trigger the last button?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I created a UIToolbar in the storyboard.

| button1 button2 button3 button4 |

In the app, when I press the space between the left edge and button1, button1 always gets triggered. However, if I press the space between button4 and the right edge, button4 is not triggered.

Is there a way to allow the right side margin to trigger button4?

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another button on the right hand side, set its alpha=0, and have it perform the same function as button 4.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know why the left side margin is working correctly?

Comment: Not sure. Could possibly have something to do with the alignment conditions you've set. Are you doing this via code or in IB or Storyboard?

Comment: The toolbar is made on storyboard.

Comment: BTW, I didn’t down vote your question. Is there a way to find out who did that?